# Dynamic number of keys in the d3 v6 rollups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 v6 rollups to create a nested data structure. I have an array 'feature_vars' that contains the variables I want to use for nested grouping. Right now, I can do this for two variables like below.

```
feature_vars = ['v0','v1']
data = d3.rollups(data, v => v.length, 
                d => d[feature_vars[0]], d=>d[feature_vars[1]]])
```

The problem is feature_vars is dynamic and can contain any number of variables. So, how do I make it generic so that is works for any number of variables in the feature_vars array?

Comment: Can you provide an example of input/output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
  const feature_vars = ['v0','v1'],
        maps = feature_vars.map(fv => function(d) {return d[fv]}),
        data = d3.rollups(data, v => v.length, ...maps)
```